# Sort the binary number based on number of 1s

Tags: python

For example: 1011 1101 010 110 1111 ==> 010 110 1011 1101 1111

I have tried the below code but it doesn't work.

```
a=[1011, 1101, 010,110,1111]           
for i in a:                           
    print(sorted (a. Count('1'))
```

Comment: there is a `key` attribute while sorting in python please have a look at that

Comment: Write a function that returns the number of `1` digits in your number.  Then specify that function as the `key` argument to the sort function/method.  It's not clear how you're trying to represent your data, but it looks like you have a list of decimal numbers that have the appearance of binary numbers.  It's a very awkward way to represent it.

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as a "binary number". Binary is a *way of writing* numbers; and when you write `1011` in Python you are *not using it* - you are writing the number one thousand and eleven. Regardless, *no* kind of number has a `Count` method, nor a `count` method, nor do they "contain" 1s in any meaningful way. To write code, you need to understand the concept of *type*. Strings and integers are different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Input the numbers as base 2:

```py
a = [int('1011',2), int('1101',2), int('010',2), int('110',2), 0b1111]
```

If you want the result to be base 2 you can map it back:

```py
b2_sorted = list(map(bin, sorted(a)))
```